# What is the difference between numeric() and as.numeric()?

Tags: r, for-loop

The code:

```
Storage<-numeric(5)
for(i in 1:5){
Storage[i]<-i^2
}
```

To store the values I create an empty vector which is "Storage". But I do not understand what "numeric(5)" means and especially what 5 means inside the numeric().

Why is just not numeric()? In Python I would do storage = [] and would this be equal to numeric()?

Comment: From `?numeric`: *numeric is identical to double (and real). It creates a double-precision vector of the specified length with each element equal to 0.*

Comment: But what would change if I used c() instead of numeric()? And I tried numeric(5) and numeric(4) both worked regardless the fact that "for( i in 1:5)" takes 5 values. It seems that argument I put in numeric() does not mean a lot.

Comment: Stick with `numeric()`, it's good, it initializes a vector of defined length and is thus more efficient than `c()` or `list()` or `NULL`.

Comment: @user19562955 The argument to `numeric` means exactly what is written in documentation. `x <- numeric(4)` creates a vector of 4 zeros. However, if you run, e.g., `x[5] <- 1` later on, `x` is extended automatically and the `1` is placed on the requested position.

Comment: That is amazing! I was exactly curious about the argument ```numeric()``` now it is clear. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can easily test why it's smart to pre-allocate a vector of the correct size by doing a simple comparison and benchmarking. To do so, we define a simple function which fills up a length 10,000 numeric vector. We can choose either to pre-allocate the vector using `numeric(10000)` or not pre-allocate it by using `c()`

```r
test <- function(preallocate) {
  Storage <- if(preallocate) numeric(10000) else c()
  for(i in 1:10000) {
    Storage[i] <- i
  }
}
```

Now let's compare how fast this function is when we toggle pre-allocation on and off:

```r
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(test(preallocate = TRUE), test(preallocate = FALSE))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                       expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>   test(preallocate = TRUE)  300.3  301.8  331.053  302.50  305.65 2762.4   100
#>  test(preallocate = FALSE) 1474.0 1498.3 1710.614 1519.15 1579.30 3998.8   100
```

We can see that it is over five times slower to write to a vector that is not pre-allocated.

Incidentally, to answer the question in your post's title, `as.numeric` and `numeric` do two different things. `numeric` creates a vector of zeros of the given length, whereas `as.numeric` attempts to convert whatever is passed to it as a numeric vector:

```r
as.numeric(5)
#> [1] 5

numeric(5)
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0

as.numeric("5")
#> [1] 5

numeric("5")
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: But interestingly when I create a vector ```x<-c(-3, 6, 2, 5, 9)``` and then create an empty vector to store the values ```storage3<-numeric(5)```  the follwing code does not work properly: ```for(i in x){storage3<-i^2}``` it gives the following outcome 9, 4, 0, 9, 25, 36, NA, NA, 81. Why would it be?

Comment: @user19562955 Because `x` is used for the _indices_ of `storage3`. In the first loop, it writes `-3^2` to element `-3 `of `storage3`. In R, writing `storage3[-3] <- 9` writes a 9 to all elements in the vector except the third, so `storage3` becomes `9, 9, 0, 9, 9`. In the second iteration, it writes 6^2 to the sixth element of `storage3`, which doesn't yet exist, but is created, so we have `9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 36`. In the third loop, we have 2^2 written to element 2, so we get `9, 4, 0, 9, 9, 36`. In the fourth loop, we have 5^2 written to element 5, giving `9, 4, 0, 9, 25, 36`

Comment: @user19562955 in the final loop, we write 9^2 to element 9. Since there is no element 7 or 8, these are filled by NA values, so we get the result of `9, 4, 0, 9, 25, 36, NA, NA, 81`

Comment: How could it give 0 then if c() does not have 0 ?

Comment: @user19562955 it shouldn't have 0. You said you used `as.numeric(5)`

Comment: I used ```storage3 <- numeric(5)```

Comment: @user19562955 yes, so you would expect element 3 to have a 0. You wouldn't get this if you used `c()`

Comment: But why element 3 is 0. Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: @user19562955 When you create `numeric(5)` You get `0, 0, 0, 0, 0`. So they all start at 0. When you do `storage3[i] <- i^2` when `i` is `-3` then this is equivalent to `storage3[-3] <- 9` which turns the vector into `9, 9, 0, 9, 9` because you are writing a 9 to all elements except the 3rd, which remains unchanged at 0.